# Left align org-mode like FoldingText

Tags: emacs, alignment, org-mode

I would love to find a way to left-align text so that paragraphs line up like in FoldingText, for example:

```
  * Headline number 1
 ** Headline number 2 [0/2]

    Here is some text before our  
    first unordered list:

  - List item 1
  - List item 2

    And here is a checklist:

  - [ ] Do this first
  - [ ] Do this next

 ** Headline number 4
```

Any ideas? Is there a minor mode that can get this done, perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do exactly what you want, but you can add `indent` option to your org file:

```
#+STARTUP: indent
```

In your .org file. Once you refresh your buffer, texts will be indented according to their headline levels (the right column of the example below):

```
 * Top level headline             |    * Top level headline
 ** Second level                  |      * Second level
 *** 3rd level                    |        * 3rd level
 some text                        |          some text
 *** 3rd level                    |        * 3rd level
 more text                        |          more text
 * Another top level headline     |    * Another top level headline
```

The example is from http://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-view.html. There are more stuff about changing outline views in the manual as well.

Comment: This is actually the way I use org-mode. It's absolutely functional. But now I'm looking to improve the... aesthetic.

Comment: I see - sorry :) Your example does look better.